# Orphan element after HTML5 sectioning element in a document outline?

Tags: html, outline

The code:

```
<section id="sec1">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <section id="sec2">section</section>
    <p id="p2">paragraph</p>
</section>
```

Question: where would be the #p2 element in a document outline? Does it belong to #sec1 or #sec2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs to #sec1 since it's not in #sec2.